# Kill the *terminal* buffer with C-d

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I found a [nice post](http://whattheemacsd.com/setup-shell.el-01.html) a few
days ago detailing how to kill the shell buffer with the `C-d` key. Basically,
after killing the process with `C-d` you can now tap `C-d` again to also kill
the buffer.

I was trying to implement something similar for term-mode, but I ran into a
problem. After you kill the term process (with the usual `C-d`) it seems that
the key-map being used by the buffer changes, but I can't find out what it is!

For example, launch the `term` command (`M-x term RET RET`) and then just
immediatelly hit `C-d`. Once the process is dead, the buffer still reports being
in term-mode, but they key-map it's using is neither `term-mode-map` nor
`term-raw-map`.

**So**
I either need to find out what map it is using so I can bind `C-d` to `kill-buffer`.
Or I need another way to kill the buffer with `C-d` in term-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Trey Jackson's version is absolutely correct, below is another version which doesn't require knowing the buffer name. It is then easier to manage multiple terminal buffers.

```lisp
(defun term-handle-exit--close-buffer (&rest args)
  (when (null (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
    (insert "Press <C-d> to kill the buffer.")
    (use-local-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                     (define-key map (kbd "C-d")
                       (lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
                     map))))
(advice-add 'term-handle-exit :after #'term-handle-exit--close-buffer)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
(defun delete-char-or-kill-terminal-buffer (N &optional killflag)
  (interactive "p\nP")
  (if (string= (buffer-name) "*terminal*")
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
(delete-char N killflag)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'delete-char-or-kill-terminal-buffer)
```

When the `*terminal*` process exits, the mode of the buffer switches to fundamental, which is why the <kbd>C-d</kbd> doesn't do what you want.