# emacs - Kill the buffer with terminal emulator

Tags: emacs

I am aware of this option:

[Kill the *terminal* buffer with C-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444265/kill-the-terminal-buffer-with-c-d)

But I am still a newbie in emacs, what is the original method to do this? I tried `C-x k` but it doesn't like it, `C-x C-c` kills all my windows and buffers...

Comment: `C-x k` should kill the current buffer. What do you mean "it doesn't like it"?

Comment: you can also type ``exit`` in the terminal to kill it

Comment: My emacs froze when I did `C-x k` and then two seconds later it just disappeared... Does it mean I may have had a faulty install?

Comment: @QuangThinhHa Type `C-h c` and then `C-x k` to confirm what command being invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using a buffer in `term-mode` (`M-x term`).  `term-mode` is a bit different than most modes in that it has two submodes, char and line.  In char mode it acts more like a terminal than emacs, as in a lot of normal keybinds are not available.  Put it in line mode with `C-c C-j` to put it in line mode, then you can run most normal keybinds including `C-x k`.  You can put it back into char mode with `C-c C-k`.

I use the `multi-term` package, which I think has better defaults than plain `term-mode` and as the name suggests makes it easy to have many terminal buffers.